# Convert Nested for loops into Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can any body convert the following nested forloop into linq query.

I have the following class definition.

```
 public class MessageCodes
{
    public string IdentityKey{ get;  set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> LangCollection { get;  set; }

    public MessageCodes()
    {
        LangCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

IdentityKey in above class is unique, LangCollection can have multiple key, values.

Say

```
 MessageCodes newCode = new MessageCodes()
                       {
                           MessageCode = "10",
                           LangCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                           {
                               {"en","Hello"},
                               {"de","dello"},
                                {"fr","fello"},
                           }
                       };

        MessageCodes oldCode = new MessageCodes()
        {
            MessageCode = "10",
            LangCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                           {
                               {"en","fello"},
                               {"de","pello"},
                               {"fr","fello"},
                           }
        };
```

Above is an example of MessageCode Instance.

Now i have collection of NewMessageCodes and OldMessageCodes.  I need to compare them 
Following is the problem nested forloop,

```
foreach (MessageCodes newMessageCode in newDiffMsgCodeCollection)
{
    foreach (MessageCodes oldMessageCode in oldDiffMsgCodeCollection)
    {
        if (newMessageCode.MessageCode == oldMessageCode.MessageCode)
        {
            MessageCodes msgCodes = new MessageCodes();
            msgCodes.MessageCode = newMessageCode.MessageCode;

            Dictionary<string, string> langCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> newLangNode in newMessageCode.LangCollection)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> oldLangNode in oldMessageCode.LangCollection)
                {
                    string newCode = newLangNode.Key.Trim().ToLower();
                    string oldCode = oldLangNode.Key.Trim().ToLower();

                    if (newCode  == oldCode )
                    {
                        if (newLangNode.Value != oldLangNode.Value)
                        {
                            langCollection.Add(newCode, oldCode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            msgCodes.LangCollection = langCollection;

        }
    }
}
```

Convert the above code mess into a Linq query or Lambda expressions.

Comment: Do you want the whole foreach into a big LINQ statment? If so that seems like a very very bad idea. If you want one of the inner foreach loops converted then please be explicit as to which one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: And please tell us what you've tried so far. This feels to me like a case where two LINQ queries would be useful: one to find the matching `MessageCodes` objects between the two collections (just a join) and another one to build the dictionary (per pair). See what you can do yourself, and edit your question to show what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: The idea is to get an o/p which doesnt show up forloops. It can have multiple linq queries.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I doesn't agree with you, I feel its a best fit here. I need a solution to a technical problem. While giving the solution they can also consider the optimization of code(not mandatorily). Is anybody has same opinion like me?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty much what you want:

```
var messageCodesQuery =
    from newMessageCode in newDiffMsgCodeCollection
    from oldMessageCode in oldDiffMsgCodeCollection
    where newMessageCode.MessageCode == oldMessageCode.MessageCode
    select new MessageCodes()
    {
        MessageCode = newMessageCode.MessageCode,
        LangCollection = (
            from newLangNode in newMessageCode.LangCollection
            from oldLangNode in oldMessageCode.LangCollection
            let newCode = newLangNode.Key.Trim().ToLower()
            let oldCode = oldLangNode.Key.Trim().ToLower()
            where newCode == oldCode
            where newLangNode.Value != oldLangNode.Value
            select new { newCode, oldCode }
        ).ToDictionary(x => x.newCode, x => x.oldCode)
    };
```

You just now need to make sure you do something with the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
newDiffMsgCodeCollection.ForEach(pd => {
                oldDiffMsgCodeCollection.ForEach(pds =>
                {
                    if (pd.MessageCode == pds.MessageCode)
                    {
                      //business logic
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: it is still nested foreach

Comment: `.ForEach(...)` is not a LINQ extension method.